# I am getting : Error(8,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored and Error(8,52): PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression in this expression

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sql-insert

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
Create or replace procedure add_services (RES_ID IN Reservation.Res_ID %TYPE, ROOM_ID IN ROOM.ROOM_ID%TYPE)

IS
BEGIN

Insert into Reservation values(RES_ID, ROOM_TYPE, select getdates(), ROOM_NUM);
Commit;

End;
```

> Error(8,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored. Error(8,52): PL/SQL:
> ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: Error(8,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored. Error(8,52): PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: You don't need a `select` when calling a function in PL/SQL. But if you do want to select a variable, in Oracle you need `(select getdates from dual)`. Are you trying to insert a single row, or multiple rows?

Comment: 1.There's no predefined function `getdates()` , 2. cannot be called as `SELECT getdates()` within an INSERT statement in that manner, even if defined. 3. Moreover, we don't know how many columns your table has totally.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

- there is no `getdates()` function in Oracle; if you want the current date/time, use `sysdate` (and there is no `select` needed).
- there are 2 input arguments for the procedure, but 3 are needed for the insert; so you would need an additional input argument to the query; I assumed you want `room_num  in room.room_num%type`

I would also recommend enumerating the target columns for `insert`. I made assumptions about the column names, and using parameter names that are different from the column names.

So:

```
create or replace procedure add_services (
    p_res_id    in reservation.res_id%type, 
    p_room_type in room.room_type%type,
    p_room_num  in room.room_num%type
)
is
begin
    insert into reservation(res_id, room_type, room_date, room_num) 
    values(p_res_id, p_room_type, sysdate, p_room_num);
    commit;
end;
```

Comment: While the above functions correctly using the same name for  a parameter and table column names, but that is an extremely bad habit to get into. You need to develop a naming convention for how your variables are used, and always stick to that convention. A common convention is to prefix parameters with p_, I tend to prefer to suffix with like "_in" or "_ot". But use whatever you and/or your team decide,.

Comment: @Belayer: yes that's a good point. I updated my answer to include that.

Comment: When i do that, Error(8,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored and   Error(8,51): PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression shows up.

Comment: @GMB: We all fall into booby traps like that at sometime.  Hopefully, we can collectively keep noobs form falling into them.

Comment: @harshil: without seeing exactly what that is, we can offer no help. What exactly gives you the error?

Comment: would u like to see my ERD?

Comment: Your ERD may be of some use, but your actual SQL that failed and the complete error message is necessary. This would likely be better as an Update section to your original rather that a replacement, but post it in the question not as a comment.  Also respond to @gogocho request.

Answer (score 0):

There is a little mixture in your code - values and insert..select.
Second - you try to call function without parametes -> this means that getdates() is not compiled successfully at all.
Another thing - why you pass RES_ID as parameter? Is this a PK column for Reservation table or something else.

And - you call ROOM_TYPE and ROOM_NUM - no such input parameters.

My advise is to pass book-in and book-out dates /this is what function suppose to return I suppose/ rather than RES_ID. But it depends from data model.

Comment: RES_ID is my PK in my column

Comment: @harshil - Can you please share Reservation table structure. PK value usually is generated by sequence but not passed as input parameter. Also I am curious what exactly this GETDATES function suppose to return. Thanks